# Excel VBA Looping formula to change Range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-2013

I've written a code to manipulate data in `L9 : DC9`, But now I need to repeat this for `L10 : DC10`, `L11 : DC11` and etc.. I've tried a `For Next` loop replacing the value in the range with `Li:DCi` and specifying (`i`) as 9 to 30 but I get an error. How can I make a loop for this function?

My current version of Excel is 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a syntax like this

```
Sub LoopRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 9 To 30
        ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i & ":DC" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This example just formats the color of the cell in each row. Notice how I use the for-loop to create a looping range selection.

Comment: Ah perfect thanks! I was afraid it would be more complex

Comment: You answered too quickly I have to wait 5 minutes, I love this website such fast help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Range("L9").Resize(21,50).Interior.Color = ..` to do it in one statement.