# EXCEL-VBA Change a range with a loop

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
```

I have the above and would like to run a loop that changes the range I use/evaluate. I have tried variations of the following.

```
for x = 2 to 10
Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Range(x & "2")
Next X
```

I have done some investigating and found this other Stack Overflow: [Excel VBA Looping formula to change Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549152/excel-vba-looping-formula-to-change-range) I can not make sense of it in this situation though.

My code will not work if it  uses cells either, I have tried that and can only make it work with Range. Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: So, using Cells() in your Range() doesn't work?  So, what happens when you try something like `Set rng = worksheets("No-Funding").Range(cells(1,1),Cells(x,2))` (What range are you trying to get? Right now, your `rng` will equate to `22`, `32`. Is that supposed to be a column, or row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a strictly numerical increment try,

```
Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Cells(x, 2)
```

An `xlA1` style reference can be achieved by factoring in the ASCII character.

```
Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Range(Chr(64 + x) & 2)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is simplicity effective and genius. I'll mark as the answer as soon as the timer passes by

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For x = 2 To 10
    Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Cells(2, x)
Next x
```

---

As far as I know it is no matter for VBA if you use function `.Range` or `.Cells`, since both of them return object or `Range` type.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Offset(0,x)
```

to move to a different column. Better yet

```
Dim values as Variant, rng as Range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Resize(10,1)
values = rng.Values2

For i=1 to 10
   values(i,1) = 2*values(i,1)
Next i

rng.Values2 = values
```