# Excel VBA plotting every column against another

Tags: excel, vba, plot, scatter-plot

It is trivial to do this in R with the command pairs(). But in Excel VBA, it seems complicated.

I have 17 columns with about 100 rows. I want to plot each column against another. Defining the range as A1:S100 is not the solution.

I should plot A vs B, A vs C, A vs D, and so on until A vs S, then B vs A, B vs C, B vs D and so on until finally S vs R. I am not able to figure out how to write a range numerically and put it in a loop. The following code won't work.

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(k1, 1), Cells(k2, N)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Comment: That is a lot of charts ...

Comment: Sometimes I will have only 6 or 5 columns. I would like to use the same macro then.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a syntax like this:

```
Sub LoopRows()
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 9 To 30
    ActiveSheet.Range("L" & i & ":DC" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
  Next i
End Sub
```

This example just formats the color of the cell in each row. Notice how I use the for-loop to create a looping range selection.

Comment: how does this answer the question about creating charts? This simply colours cells in a loop...

Comment: Looping columns is where my problem is. I am just a beginner. I have to use numbers and not "A" and "C".

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a steer. With 17 columns I think you will be in trouble.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, c1 As Long, c2 As Long, ch As Chart

Set r = Range("A1:D20")

For c1 = 1 To r.Columns.Count
    For c2 = 1 To r.Columns.Count
        If c1 <> c2 Then
            Set ch = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            ch.ChartType = xlXYScatter
            ch.SetSourceData Source:=Union(r.Columns(c1), r.Columns(c2))
        End If
    Next c2
Next c1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to learn this thing: Union(r.Columns(c1),r.Columns(c2))

What is the point of Set r = Range("A1:D20")? Can the whole table from Ctrl-home to Ctrl-end (Rows.Count, Columns.Count) not be the range?

Comment: Yes you can define the range however you like, that was just an example.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Defining the range is precisely what I am trying to learn. How do I specify say rows 3 to 20 of column 8 against rows 3 to 20 of column 15? When I plot the series manually, I can see what Excel writes, but how do I change those numbers to specify them as (integer or long) variables?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to do all combinations, but only selected ones? In the code above you could use `Union(r.Columns(8), r.Columns(15))` and define `r` accordingly.

Comment: No, no. Your solution is perfect for my actual work, but I am also trying to learn in parallel. If I plot manually, I get something like =SERIES(,Sheet1!$F$3:$F$8,Sheet1!$H$3:$H$8,1). How I can write this in terms of variables? Is there a decent way? Say I do not want the whole column but a limited set from row k1 to row k2.

Comment: If you define a range variable then you can access its properties such as address which will return a string like $F$3:$F$8. This sounds like it's veering towards a different sort of question so you might want to consider starting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Cells(x, 2)
Set rng = Worksheets("No-Funding").Range(Chr(64 + x) & 2)
```

For more information, please review the following link:
   [EXCEL-VBA Change a range with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678789/excel-vba-change-a-range-with-a-loop)